# PostgreSQL verify an empty array on json

Tags: sql, json, postgresql

I have the following row on select

```
jsonData
[]
[{"descricao":"falha na porta"}, {"descricao":"falha no ip"}]
[]
```

I have to Identify empty jsons, then manually add a value to it (eg row 1 and 3 ), I tried the following :

```
case when jsonData is null then cast('[{"descricao":"no error"}]' AS json) else jsonData   end as opts
```

But the "is null" verification fails for this type of data (array of json), how to identify '[]' values in this case?

Note: I only have select permission on this db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this condition:

```
jsondata = JSON '[]'
```

Comment: ERROR: operator does not exist: json = jsonb Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types, also the same occurs when using these: jsondata = JSON '[]' and jsondata = '[]' :: json

Comment: However worked using jsondata::text =  '[]' , Your suggestion helped me reach this answer thanks.

Comment: @RenanFernandes: the other option is to cast your `json` column to `jsonb` (which it should be anyways): `jsondata::jsonb = jsonb '[]'`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `json_array_length()`

```
when json_array_length(jsondata) = 0 then ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Casting the json to text before comparison worked for this case :
" `case when jsondata::text = '[]'` "